# ST_SnaptoGrid not working properly

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to perform ST_SnaptoGrid on a line but the result is very strange. I tested this line of code on 3 separate postgis sessions and the results of all of them was the same:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SnapToGrid(
        ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(334729.13 4103548.88,334729.12 4103548.5300000003)'),
        0.001)
    );
```

The result is :

```
LINESTRING(334729.13 4103548.88,334729.12 4103548.5300000003)
```

The strange part is that when I test it with a different cell size:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SnapToGrid(
        ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(334729.13 4103548.88,334729.12 4103548.5300000003)'),
        0.1)
    );
```

It results to:

```
LINESTRING(334729.10000000003 4103548.9000000004,334729.10000000003 4103548.5)
```

Another example of a strange behavor is running this code:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SnapToGrid(
    ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(334729.13 4103548.88,334729.12 4103548.53)'),
    0.001)
);
```

results in:

```
LINESTRING(334729.13 4103548.88,334729.12 4103548.5300000003)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Consider revising your post and let us know what specific outcome you are looking for.

Comment: You may want to ask this question in gis.stackexchange also have a look at this
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358423/st-snaptogrid-makes-result-invalid-depending-on-size

Comment: I edited the post and added another strange behavior.